# Is prius plural for prius?

Tags: grammar

Similar to sheep.

Look at that sheep. Look at those sheep.

Look at that prius. Look at those prius.

Sounds right.

Comment: If you mean the Toyota Prius, the official plural is *[Prii](http://toyotanews.pressroom.toyota.com/releases/toyota-announces-the-plural-of-prius.htm)*; Toyota ran a whole marketing campaign around it.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, *Prius* comes from a Latin word meaning *former, ahead, at the front*, of which the plural is *priora*.

Comment: @Anonym You’re mostly right.  *Prius* occurs in certain inflections of [the standard Latin comparative-degree *prior*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prior#Latin), which is an **adjective** of the ***third*** declension rather than a **noun** of the second. And although the superlative degree of *prior* is *primus*, there is no positive degree. BTW, these are all related to the common **prefix** *pre-*. It’s like if we had only *earlier* and *earliest* but not *early* in English, or if there were a superlative degree of *former* but no positive degree.

Comment: Sounds right??? Look at that bus. *Look at those bus. Measure this circle's radius. *Measure these circles' radius.